# Как поймать событие открытия/закрытия дисковода?

Tags: javascript, node.js, диск, electron

Существуют ли методы для фиксирования открытия/закрытия дисковода (есть диск/нет диска) средствами JavaScript/Electron (ранее известный как Atom Shell)?

Answer (score 1):

Electron это по сути Node.js, а нодой можно проверить сделав на диск скажем *fs.readdir()* , если там ничего нет то будет ошибка. Ну или можно пойти дальше и написать **C/C++ Addon**

Comment: а как отличить дисковод от, например, остальных томов?

Comment: Думаю что напрямую без С/С++ никак, можно поиграться с запуском консольных команд и парсингом вывода, но это для каждой OS свой подход нужен, я бы лучше неписал небольшой C++ addon.

Comment: есть пакет для node под названием "win-eject", который позволяет управлять дисководом(открыть/закрыть), там есть метод, возвращающий массив с указание подключенных дисководов. Там все реализовано с помощью  VBS, но имеются проблемы с JSON-форматом(по всей видимости приходит неправильный ответ от VBS-скрипта). Я просто не знаком ни с **C** ни с **C++**, так только, когда-то калькулятор писал, не больше)

Comment: На C можно просто взять где-то пример и адаптировать его в Node, если нужно возвращать простые значения то это не так сложно